# Will WCF use the same ParameterInspector instance to handle BeforeCall and AfterCall?

Tags: wcf

If I create a class that implements IParameterInspector, and insert it into the WCF pipline using a custom ServiceBehavior, will the same instance of the class be used when invoking BeforeCall and AfterCall?  In other words, can I establish state about the current invocation during BeforeCall that I can access in AfterCall, and be sure that the response will come to the same instance?

Note _stateValue in the sample code below?  Can I depend on a mechanism like this?

```
class OperationParameterInspector : IParameterInspector
{
    public int _stateValue;

    public object BeforeCall(string operationName, object[] inputs)
    {
        _stateValue = (int) inputs[0];
        return null;
    }

    public void AfterCall(string operationName, object[] outputs, object returnValue, object correlationState)
    {
        int originalInput = _stateValue;
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: The more I think about this, it seems like there is only one instance of the class for ALL requests, which means internal state doesn't work, because all requests and responses will be passing through, probably on multiple threads.  If anyone has insight on how to establish and maintain state in the pipeline before and after an incoming WCF request, I'd like to here about it.

Comment: [Make Object ID](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/03/04/make-objectid-vstipdebug0015.aspx) is very useful when trying to figure this type of question.

Comment: I didn't know this behaviour too. Even if the service configuration is set to instance per call, the interception occurs on a single instance. Hard to predict. Banging my head to walls for a few good days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing state related to a particular call is the purpose of the return value from `BeforeCall` and the `correlationState` argument of `AfterCall`. The WCF infrastructure ensures that whatever object you return from `BeforeCall` is then passed into `AfterCall` via the `correlationState`, after the operation has completed.

As your subsequent comment suggests, the problem with using instance state in the inspector object is that instances may be shared between concurrent requests in some scenarios. However, I don't think there are any scenarios where a single operation request would be served by different parameter inspector objects in BeforeCall and AfterCall.